# find a query string in url

Tags: string, pattern-matching, preg-match, query-string

I have a url, like an string

```
http://www.php.net/index.php?page=mypage&keywords=mykeyword&title=mytitle
```

I want to grab "mykeyword" as it is the value for keyword query part and I just have the url as an sting not the php page code for index.php

I know I should do stuff with string match and some php functions like "preg_match" but I dont know how to use thme

maybe I should cut off the url to parts joining with "&" and go to the value after "="

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the URL as string you can use parse_str.

```
$str = "http://www.php.net/index.php?page=mypage&keywords=mykeyword&title=mytitle";

parse_str($str);

echo $keywords;
```

If you want to request it from URL you can use $_REQUEST['keywords']

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I never used it, but this function looks very promising:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

And i recommend using the output parameter variable to keep your $_GET and $_POST variables untouched.